# Dynamically change element name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is my element `id` and I want to update it dynamically.

```
invoice[46][ap_details][4][ap_header_id]
```

I want to update only second number, i.e. `[4]`, like this:

```
invoice[46][ap_details][5][ap_header_id]
```

I am using below code which is updating both the values.

```
var strNewName = $(this).attr('name').replace(/\[\d+\]/g, function(strName) {
    strName = strName.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
    var intNumber = parseInt(strName) + 1;
    return '[' + intNumber + ']';
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us why? This may be optimized elsewhere!

Comment: maybe addClass / removeClass is a better way to go..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var strName = "invoice[46][ap_details][4][ap_header_id]";

var parts = strName.split('[');
parts[3] = parts[3].replace(/^\d+/, n => +n + 1);

var strNewName = parts.join('[');
console.log(strNewName);
```

If you don't want to use **arrow functions** replace this line:

```
parts[3] = parts[3].replace(/^\d+/, n => +n + 1);
```

with this:

```
parts[3] = parts[3].replace(/^\d+/, function(n) { return +n + 1; });
```

**Explanation:**

`split` will return an array like this:

```
[
  "invoice",
  "46]",             // parts[1] to change this
  "ap_details]",
  "4]",              // parts[3] to change this (and so on, you do the math)
  "ap_header_id]"
]
```

The `/^\d+/` will match any number at the begining (no need for the `g` modifier).

Replace with `+n + 1` not `n + 1` because `n` is a string, you have to force the interpretter to use it as a number or otherwise this `"4" + 1` will result to this `"41"`.

Then after you change what you want, join the parts using `join` with the same character you used for splitting (`[`).

Answer (score 1):

Using this regex `/((\w)+)(\[\d+\])(\[(\w)+\])(\[\d+\])(\[(\w)+\])/gi` you can construct the string back and change your integer.

```
var match = /((\w)+)(\[\d+\])(\[(\w)+\])(\[\d+\])(\[(\w)+\])/gi.exec(youString);
//group 6 is your digit.
var newId = parseInt(match[6].replace("\[\]", "")) + 1;
var newString = match[1] + match[3] + match[4] + "[" + newId + "]" + match[7];
```

Here is a fiddle with the answer https://jsfiddle.net/gzfud9vc/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe dont use regex to build your element id. You can do its as follows as well:

```js
var id = 5
var name = "invoice[46][ap_details][";
name += id;
name += "][ap_header_id]";

var toReplace = "invoice[46][ap_details][~~id~~][ap_header_id]"
var replaced = toReplace.replace(/~~id~~/g, id);

console.log(name);
console.log(replaced);
```